# Loading content on a webpage before 'Playing'

Tags: javascript, html, css, mp4

I guess this is a pretty simple question but I was wondering if I could load the contents of my webpage before a browser attempts to play or stream a certain mp4 file that is on the webpage

The reason why I have to do this is because chrome will stream it and play it fine as it loads but other browsers such as safari will want to load the entire file before playing. This however gives no indication to the user.

So ideally I would like it to load the necessary mp4 file before it starts playing. Obviously I would need some sort of loading screen to appear first and once everything was loaded the website would continue.

If this is possible where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeot() after page is loaded.

```
function playFunc(){
  // The code to play your mp4
}

document.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ playFunc() },3000); //Execute playFunc() after 3000 millisecond
}
```